# Explicit arithmetic, Does the compiler take care of it?

Tags: c, compilation

Sometimes I find it's easier to understand code (for yourself in the future or others) by being explicit about arithmetic.  E.g. writing 1+2+3 if you're adding 3 values from elsewhere, rather than a single magic number +6.

Is this inefficient or would a compiler optimize/reduce it appropriately?  I'm thinking about C but in general is this something to worry about?

Comment: Yes (or if it doesn't, you should throw that compiler away, and get one written this century).

Comment: `1 + 2 + 3` is a *constant*, which the compiler can resolve and replace with `6`. `a + b + c`, where `a`, `b`, and `c` are variables, cannot be optimized by the compiler, as the value assigned to the variables can't be determined at compile time.

Comment: (Even dynamic languages implementations, like those for JavaScript, *can* apply constant folding/evaluation in such cases. Complications arise in languages that allow operator overloading on the types involved..)

Comment: Even if the compiler *didn't* reduce 1+2+3 to a constant, the resulting performance hit will probably not be noticeable for any but the most hard-core performance sensitive algorithms.

Comment: @user2864740: Not all languages though. For example, in Ruby, `1+2` is not optimised, since `1` could have its `+` method redefined.

Comment: @Amadan Nitpick: that has less to do with dynamic languages insofar as such overloads being allowed that result in a non-intrinsic computation.

Comment: If 1,2,3` has meaning, `1+2+3` is much better magic `6`.  But watch out for `2/3` which is `0` due to integer division.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. All competent C compilers will perform [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) optimizations where possible, replacing constant mathematical expressions with their results. In most compilers, this type of optimization is applied even when optimizations are otherwise disabled (e.g, `-O0`). [Here's an example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22JYOwLgBGAWBOCm8AUA3A9sAJgSggbwCgJiEwBXWECARggGoIAmAbgIF8gAA%3D%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O0%22%7D%5D%7D).

This behavior is not restricted to C; most other compiled languages will perform this type of optimization as well. Interpreted languages typically do not, as the benefits are less dramatic there, and some of them may have semantics which may make constant folding an unsafe optimization (e.g, allowing basic operations to be overridden on builtin types).